# Infinite scroll on "pageshow" jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, infinite-scroll

I'm having some trouble in understanding what goes wrong with the infinite scroll plugin (Paul Irish) when navigating from page to a new one within the jQueryMobile framework.

When page re-loads, everything works fine and I get the next page injected into the DOM on scroll, when navigating to a section i.e. "Editorials" from the fly-out menu "+ Photography", I get the infinite scroll plugin "heading into ajax" loading up the wrong page along with the right one. This causes an error and an unbind of the infinite scroll to the page.

Here's the troubled site http://www.elisabettaclaudio.com

and here's the console log:

```
["heading into ajax", Array[2] ] jquery.infinitescroll.js:183
["Using HTML via .load() method"] jquery.infinitescroll.js:183
["heading into ajax",  Array[2] ] jquery.infinitescroll.js:183
["Using HTML via .load() method"] 
XHR finished loading: "http://www.elisabettaclaudio.com/editorials/?pg=2".
["contentSelector",  <div class=​"mas masonry" style=​"position:​ relative;​ height:​ 448.79999923706055px;​ ">​…​</div>​ ] jquery.infinitescroll.js:183
XHR finished loading: "http://www.elisabettaclaudio.com/editorials/?pg=4". jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4
["Error", "end"] jquery.infinitescroll.js:183
["Binding", "unbind"]
```

Can't work out what is causing this bearing in mind that when disabling the jqm ajax navigation, everything works as expected.

Here's the javascript

```
// Remove Default section
$('.type-home').live('pagehide', function(){        
$(this).remove();
}); 

// Remove InfiniteScroll from previous section
$('.type-home').live('pagebeforehide', function(){  
$('.mas').infinitescroll('destroy');    
});     

// Bind InfiniteScroll to next section
$('.type-home').live('pagebeforeshow', function(){
$('.mas').infinitescroll('bind');
});     


$(document).bind('pageshow', function() {
    if($('.mas').length){     

      // Masonry
      var $wall = $('.mas');      

      // Ensure that images load before executing Masonry
      $wall.imagesLoaded(function(){
         $wall.masonry({
             itemSelector: '.set',
             isAnimated: false,
             animationOptions: {
                duration: 100,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
              }
             }); 

        // Show itemSelector 
        var sequenza = $('.set'), i = 0;    
        (function(){
            $(sequenza[i++] || []).animate({opacity: 1}, 100, arguments.callee);
        })();   


     $wall.infinitescroll({ 
      state: {
        isDuringAjax: false,
        isInvalidPage: false,
        isDestroyed: false,
        isDone: false,
        isPaused: false,
        currPage: 1
  },
        navSelector : '.nav-selector a',  // selector for the paged navigation 
        nextSelector : '.nav-selector a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
        itemSelector : ".set",
    contentSelector: ".mas",
        loadingImg : 'css/themes/default/images/ajax-loader.png',
        donetext : 'No more to load.',
        animate : false,
        behaviour : 'masonry-isotope',
        bufferPx : 10,
        extraScrollPx: 0,
        debug : true,
        dataType: 'html+callback',
        appendCallback: true,
        errorCallback : function() { 
         //fade out the error message after 2 seconds
         $('#infscr-loading').animate({opacity: .18}, 2000).fadeOut('slow');

        }
      },
        // call masonry as a callback.
        function(newElements) { 

        // Define new elements
        var $newElems = $(newElements);

        $($newElems).animate({opacity: 0}, 0);

        // Ensure that images load before exectuing Masonry 
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){

                        // initialise Masonry for method 'appended' soon after
            $wall.masonry();

            // Use the append method will position only th new added elements
            $wall.masonry('appended', $newElems, true );

                // Fade in new elements in linear sequence
                var sequenzaNew = $newElems, i = 0; 

                (function() {
                    $(sequenzaNew[i++] || []).animate({opacity: 1}, 100,
                    arguments.callee);
                })();

            });     
        });

        // Check window height against document height and force loading
        setInterval(function(){
            var windowHeight = $(window).height();  
            var docHeight = $(document).height();   


            if(windowHeight >= docHeight){

            $wall.infinitescroll('retrieve', console.log('Force retrieve infinite scroll'));

        } else if(windowHeight < docHeight) { 

        console.log('Now wait for a scoll');    

        };
        }, 2000);


});  
};
});
```

Comment: I guess that the Ajax navigation is keeping an instance of the "contentSelector" in the DOM and this triggers the ".load" method any time a new page is injected in the DOM. On refresh everything or Ajax navigation disabled everything works fine as there's only one instance of the "contentSelector".

Comment: This is working now by forcing a "destroy" on "pagehide" and a "bind" on "pageshow" of the infinite scroll.